# Some doubts about predicate calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I am studying the **predicate calculus** in First Order Logic and I have some doubt about this argument.  In my book I find that a formula in the predicate calculus is built from

- **Literals** constructed from
- - **Predicate Symbols**: $P = \{p,q\}$
- - **Constants**: $A = \{a,b\}$
- - **Variables**: $X = \{x,y\}$
- **Logical Connectives**:  (and, or, not, implication, etc)
- **Quantifiers**: (univeral and existential)

To build a syntactically correct formula I can use a BNF grammar.

So for example this one is a **valid predicative forumla**:

$$ \forall x.\exists y.(p(x,y) \to p(y,x)) $$

My question is: “what exactly is p?“

I think that $p$ is a predicate that represents a 2-ary relation. For example $p$ could be something like the relation that represent whether a number is the square root of another number. So for example:

\begin{gather}
SQ(2,1) = F \\
SQ(2,2) = F \\
SQ(2,3) = F \\
SQ(2,4) = T
\end{gather}

So if $p$ represents a 2-ary relation it is a subset of the $2\times 2$ cartesian product (in the previous case it is only the point that the first number is the square root of the second number).

So $p$ is a predicate that represents a $n$-ary relation $R$ on a domain $D$ and $R$ is a subset of $D^n$.

So, the predicate $p$ related to $R$ is true if:

$$R(d_1,\dots,d_n) = T \text{ iff } \langle d_1,\dots,d_n\rangle \in R $$

So, coming back to my previous predicative formula, can I say that it is built from some **predicative symbol that uses variables and constants connected together by logical connectives, and in which I can “select” some or all variables by the universal and existential quantifiers?**

Comment: You're mixing up *variables*, which are a syntactic thing, which elements of a *universe*. $\exists x$ and $\forall x$ make $x$ range over all elements of the *universe* (and check whether the formula holds for one respectively all of them), *not* over other variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predicate symbol $p$ is part of the language. It has no meaning. It can only be part of a well formed formula. The interpretation of that language is a structure. It is in that structure that $p$ is interpreted as an $n$-ary relation on a given universe.

Let's use your square root predicate as an example. Suppose the symbol is 'SQ' and it is given in our language as a binary predicate symbol. Since it is a binary predicate $SQ(t_1,t_2)$ is a formula for any two terms $t_1$ and $t_2$ of our language. That is really all we can say about 'SQ' without a structure.

Now, if we have a structure that interprets our language, it must give meaning to a formula like $SQ(1,2)$, where $1$ and $2$ are also terms in our language. In your example, you interpreted this as meaning "the square root of $2$ is $1$". This is probably going to be evaluated as false in the structure you had in mind.

Comment: Ok, so what you're saying to me is that: SQ(t1,t2) is a generic bynary PREDICATIVE SYMBOL of my language and that t1 and t2 could be any terms of my language. And if I would that SQ predicative symbol have the square root as meaning I have to impose the constraint that the t1 and t2 terms are integers number. But what exactlry are t1 and t2? variables? (a variable IS A term?) Tnx so much

Comment: @AndreaNobili $t_1$ and $t_2$ are terms in your language. They are built by applying your function symbols to constants, variables and other terms.

Comment: mmm I am not understanding...what you mean when you say: " They are built by applying your function symbols to constants, variables and other terms"?

Comment: Suppose $0$, $1$ are constants, $v_1, v_2, ...$ are variables and $+$ is a binary function symbols. $0$ is a term, $(0+1)$ is a term, $(((v_{10}+1)+(0+0)) + (v_1+v_2))$ is a term, etc. You build the terms of your language from the functions and you build the formulas from relations on terms.

Comment: Ok this is pretty clear to me but I would know if in predicative calculus, if I have something like SQ(x,y) (where SQ(x,y) is a terms and x, y are variables) I can impose that the meaning of SQ(x,y) is the square root relation between x and y, appling the constraint that x and y are integer number and giving a boolean interpetation to SQ terms. Can I do this thing?

Comment: Yes, but you do that in a structure for the language. In this case it sounds like the universe of your structure would be the set of integers and for each pair of integers you evaluate whether or not the predicate is true.

Comment: Ok, and how I do it? For example I build my predicative formulas using a simple BNF grammar. For example I could specify in this BNF grammar that the value of x,y variables could be only a value take from the integer number set? Something like it?

Comment: In your particular example, we would say For $m,n\in \mathbb Z$, $(m,n)\in SQ(t_1,t_2)$ if $t_1(m)=\sqrt{t_2(n)}$.